# Catching that a validation rule has been violated to prevent user from saving

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

I have several textboxes that I want to enforce certain rules on. For example, I have a Name textbox that is binded to a Name property, and I don't want any | < or > characters present in that property. In order to do that, I created the following class that inherits from ValidationRule:

```
class NoInvalidCharsRule : ValidationRule
{
    private static char[] mInvalidChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        String stringValue = value.ToString();

        foreach (char invalidChar in mInvalidChars)
        {
            if (stringValue.Contains(invalidChar))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Invalid characters are present in the string.");
            }
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, "");
    }
}
```

and is binded as follows in my .xaml:

```
    <pres:OneTextBox Watermark="Name..." Margin="85,12,0,0"
                     AcceptsReturn="False" MaxLines="1" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Style="{StaticResource ErrorStyleTextBox}">
        <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <pres:OneTextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="InterfaceSpecification.Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" >
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <interfaceSpecsModule:NoInvalidCharsRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </pres:OneTextBox.Text>
    </pres:OneTextBox>
```

There is also a "Done" button and I would like that if there are invalid characters in the Name textbox, that button should be disabled or when clicked, a popup window appears telling the user that there are invalid characters.

For now, the code that I have done only highlights in red the textbox if such characters are present. How would I be able to disable the button if invalid characters are found in the textbox?

EDIT: I know that once an invalid character is written in the textbox, the Name property stops being updated. Unfortunately, it still contains everything before that invalid character and I would like to stop the user from saving that name (by pressing the done button) with only a few valid characters instead of the full name he was intending to input.

Comment: Question is, what is OneTextBox? Does it derive from TextBox?

Comment: @BlueM Yes, it derives from TextBox. I am using a custom framework that encapsulates almost each WPF controls to enhance their functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you name your textbox nameTextBox it would be:

```
<Button Name="doneButton" Content="Done" IsDefault="True">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=nameTextBox, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

You can specify more conditions if needed.

Comment: Is there a way to show a message box instead of disabling it? That would be my preferred solution if possible.

Comment: Then you have to check the validation results of each element in your Done button command handler.

Comment: @Choub890 Due to usability I would not popup a message box. Better show a red hint right above the text box about the problem immediately when there is an error. This is more modern and doesn't hinder the flow. This may be of help => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753206/wpf-validation-errors-how-to-show-in-separate-textblock-not-in-tooltip